Как получить текст после тега <br>?
Как мне получить текст после тега <br> без пробела перед текстом? Нужно получить такой текст "CAA Chubu". Уже час не могу сообразить. Вот структура страницы:
Я получил нужный тег td, а дальше я не знаю как мне извлечь из HTML коллекции нужную информацию, вот код:
<td class="media_v1 korea_auc_no"><center>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td style="padding-top:2px">
        <nobr>11.12.2024<br>
        <span style="color:#999;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px">[12:36]</span><br>
        CAA Chubu</nobr>
      </td>
      <td style="line-height:0.9em;padding-left:20px;font-weight:13px;font-family:Cuprum,Tahoma;color:#e38553;">2 дней<br>назад</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </center></td>

.
const elementDiv = document.getElementById("table_main");
const elementAuc = document.querySelectorAll(".korea_auc_no.media_v1");

if (elementDiv) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'DivClass';
    div.innerHTML += "Тут будет текст";
    elementDiv.after(div);
}
if (elementAuc) {
    console.log(elementAuc[1]);
}

Мне нужно из "elementAuc" получить текст "CAA Chubu" без пробелов по бокам.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Структуру из скрина привидите текстом и покажите, что уже удалось сделать

Для первого элемента document.querySelectorAll(".media_v1.korea_auc_no")[0].querySelector('nobr').childNodes[5].textContent Если надо все, то делать это в цикле document.querySelectorAll(".media_v1.korea_auc_no").forEach(e => console.log(querySelector('nobr').childNodes[5].textContent))

Не работает, ругается на querySelector текстовый редактор. И ошибка в браузере Cannot read properties of null (reading 'childNodes')

@KickBoxerK1, ругается на то, что перед  querySelector пропущена переменная цикла. Должно быть e.querySelector. Других ошибок у SwaD нет. Разве что после .textContent нужно дописать .trim() для удаления закравшихся пробелов в начале строки.

В общем сделал так:
elementAuc.textContent.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, " ").trim());

Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но главное - работает.
